# Replace A: One Property in ViewModel for each TextBox with B: One property returning a (observable) collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, properties

Let's have these two enumerations and a model class:

```
public enum A
{
    A1,
    A2,
    A3,
    A4
}
public enum B
{
    B1,
    B2,
    B3
}

// model class
public class MyModel
{
    private float[][] array;

    public MyModel()
    {
        array = new float[Enum.GetNames(typeof(A)).Length][];
        foreach (A a in EnumUtil.GetValues<A>())
        {
            array[(int) a] = new float[Enum.GetNames(typeof(B)).Length];
        }
    }

    public A EnumerationA { get; set; }
    public B EnumerationB { get; set; }
    public float this[A a, B b]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[(int) a][(int) b];
        }
        set
        {
            array[(int)a][(int)b] = value;
        }
    }
    public float[] ArraySlice
    {
        get
        {
            return array[(int) EnumerationA];
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say we would like to implement a view having a group of RadioButtons for enum A, and for each enum B we'd like a TextBox.
Changing a radio button in radiobutton group would allow to edit different set of values in TextBoxes, changing back would display previously entered values.
[image]

The most simple way, i can think of, to do this is:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyModel _myModel;

    public A EnumerationA
    {
        get
        {
            return _myModel.EnumerationA;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Enum.Equals(_myModel.EnumerationA, value) == false)
            {
                _myModel.EnumerationA = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EnumerationA");
            }
        }
    }

    public float ValueB1
    {
        get
        {
            return _myModel[EnumerationA, B.B1];
        }
        set
        {
            if (_myModel[EnumerationA, B.B1] != value)
            {
                _myModel[EnumerationA, B.B1] = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ValueB1");
            }
        }
    }
    // Analogously for ValueB2 and ValueB3 properties

}
```

And the View:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>      
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Enum A" />  
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnumerationA, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:A.A1}}" Content="A1" />
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnumerationA, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:A.A2}}" Content="A2" />
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnumerationA, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:A.A3}}" Content="A3" />
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnumerationA, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:A.A4}}" Content="A4 />
  </StackPanel>

  <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Float Values" />  
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Label Content="B1" /><TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValueB1}" /></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Label Content="B2" /><TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValueB2}" /></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Label Content="B3" /><TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValueB3}" /></StackPanel>    
  </StackPanel>

 </Grid>
```

That is, this approach creates a property for each TextBox and performs PropertyNotification when the radiobutton group selection changes.

**Question:**
Is it possible to do this in such a way that the ViewModel would only expose a single property instead of three properties (ValueB1, ValueB2, ValueB3):
this single property would return an ObservableCollection<> or IList (or something similar with index selection)?

---

*I thought about one possible way this might be done:*
in VM we would have something like

```
    public ObservableCollection<float> ArraySlice
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<float>(_myModel.ArraySlice);
        }

    }
```

in View

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Label Content="B1" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=WindSpeedAverage, Converter={StaticResource EnumToObservableCollectionConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:B.B1}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This EnumToObservableCollectionConverter - one way it's easy, it would cast the value as IList and simply return IList[parameter], but it's the other way I am confused about...
Even if I implemented ConvertBack method, I would simply update just the ObservableCollection and not the value itself in the model class.

**How can this be done? Is there a common pattern for this that I am missing**

Comment: So, you wish to select the B-textboxes block by selecting one of the A-radios: is that correct? In other words, you have a matrix of values to be edited, and the radio-buttons should select the "row"?

Comment: @MarioVernari Basically, yes. The code that I posted does that, but I am interested in knowing what is the common pattern for doing it without the need to have a property in ViewModel for each TextBox. Ideally I would want to expose just one property that returns an array/collection/interface and wire it up in view. This should not break the ability to have two-way binding and should propagate the values into the model class instance in ViewModel as well.

Answer (score 0):

First off, my apologies: I answered on the last-minute before leaving the office.

So, here is how I would approach your problem, but there are many other solutions. It's a rough yet minimal way to create a GUI as you wish (as far I understand correctly).

Let's start from the viewmodels: your case looks a simple master-detail context, but it could be seen as an hierarchical context as well.

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        this._aItems = new ObservableCollection<VMA>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<VMA> _aItems;

    public Collection<VMA> AItems
    {
        get { return this._aItems; }
    }
}


public class VMA
{
    public VMA()
    {
        this._bItems = new ObservableCollection<VMB>();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<VMB> _bItems;

    public Collection<VMB> BItems
    {
        get { return this._bItems; }
    }
}


public class VMB : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set
        {
            if (this._value != value)
            {
                this._value = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Please, note that the "Value" property is of type "string" despite the target value should constrained to a float. That's because a string is always accepted, and you could implement your own validation logic. Instead, a numerical property may lead to exceptions whereas the entered characters are not allowed as a number.

The above viewmodels are populated in the following way (as for example):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var rnd = new Random();
        var vm = new VM();
        this.DataContext = vm;

        //enum "A"
        foreach (var a in Enum.GetNames(typeof(A)))
        {
            var vma = new VMA();
            vma.Title = a;
            vm.AItems.Add(vma);

            //enum "B"
            foreach (var b in Enum.GetNames(typeof(B)))
            {
                var vmb = new VMB();
                vmb.Title = b;
                vmb.Value = rnd.Next(1000).ToString();
                vma.BItems.Add(vmb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't use the model for sake of simplicity, but you may add it anytime. Instead, I chose to populate with random integers.

Finally, here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" Width="525"
        >

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="tplA">
            <RadioButton
                Content="{Binding Path=Title}"
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="tplB">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="30" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="100" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AItems}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tplA}"
            Width="150"
            Height="200"
            Grid.Column="0"
            x:Name="L1"
            >
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.BItems, ElementName=L1}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tplB}"
            Width="150"
            Height="200"
            Grid.Column="1"
            >
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The visual result looks like the following picture.

[image]